# How can I replace the instanced of a type by wrapping around the constructor?

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have a legacy lib that creates instances of `BeanProxy`. Unfortunately this implementation has a flaw I would like to fix. As I don't want to start working with patched libs, I wanted to create an Aspect wrapping the construction of `BeanProxy` and return an instance of my modified `BeanProxy` sub-type.

I created the following Aspect and it is correctly woven and called whenever a new instance of `BeanProxy` is created:

```
@Aspect
public class CWebBeanProxyInjectingAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public flex.messaging.io.BeanProxy.new(..))")
    void createBeanProxy() {}

    @Around("createBeanProxy()")
    public Object createAlternateBeanProxy(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("createAlternateBeanProxy");
        final Object result = pjp.proceed();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `result` is always `null` ... what am I doing wrong? What do I have to change?
I should mention, that I am using AspectJ LoadTimeWeaving and the spring-instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar as agent.

Comment: If the original library's objects implement interfaces, you can always use composition

Comment: Well the waeving seems to work, just I think that I am using it the wrong way ... as result is allways "null". I was expecting it to be the instance of the BeanProxy class that was just created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructor `execution` don't return anything (is `void`). If you want to return the created object, use `call` in your pointcut:

```
  @Pointcut("call(public flex.messaging.io.BeanProxy.new(..))")
    void createBeanProxy() {}
```

see *Contstructor call* and *Constructor execution* in 
http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-joinPoints.html

Comment: Thanks for that ... unfortunately it seems that "call" isn't supported when using the normal LTW ... I did try creating a dedicated Aspect (.aj-file) and somehow integrating this into my build but I think I would have to learn quite a bit more about this if I didn't want to mess up the other aspects I am already using. I decided to solve my problem differentyl by wrapping around the "getValue" method of BeanProxy using and doing my magic there. It's not as clean as I hoped, but it works and that's currently good enough for me :-)